# mongoose $pull to delete elements from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When I run the following code to delete (`$pull`) an element from an array, it does not remove that item. Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

```
App.update(
  { $and : [{name : "appName"} , { _id : { $in : appIds} }]},
  { $pull : { intent_ids : intent.id } }, // <<--- THIS DOESN'T WORK
  function(err) if (err) throw err;
  res.send(200);
});
```

Comment: Hard to follow your question, can you show us your schema definitions for `Intent`, `User` and `App` models?

Comment: @chridam just updated my post with that info. Thanks!